# Can you arrange a Flexdashboard by rows and columns?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I'm trying to create a large dashboard for a 65" display. I have data that consists of varying (1-4) parameters per group with 1 main parameter. I would like to display these groups with one main graph and the parameters graphed individually below it:

```
[MAIN------GRAPH1]  [MAIN------GRAPH4]
[PAR1][PAR2][PAR3]  [PAR1][PAR2][PAR3]

[MAIN------GRAPH2]  [MAIN------GRAPH5]
[PAR---1][PAR---2]  [PAR1][PAR2][PAR3]

[MAIN------GRAPH3]  [MAIN------GRAPH6]
[PAR1][PAR2][PAR3]  [PAR---1][PAR---2]
```

I have tried arranging the flexdashboard by rows but the result isn't working as expected.

Here's what I have so far:

````
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: rows
source_code: embed
---
Row {data-height=650}
-------------------------------------

### Chart1

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(dygraphs)
library(flexdashboard)
library(readr)
library(xts)

```
```{r}
graph 
```

Row {data-height=350}
-------------------------------------

### Chart1Par1

```{r}
first parameter
```   

### Chart1Par2

```{r}
second parameter
```
Row {data-height=650}
-------------------------------------

### Chart2

```{r}
second chart main
```

Row {data-height=350}
-------------------------------------

### Chart2Par1

```{r}

```   

### Chart2Par2

 ```{r}

 ```
````

I'm expecting:

```
[MAIN------GRAPH1]
[PAR---1][PAR---2]

[MAIN-----------2]
[PAR2--1][PAR2--2]
```

I'm getting:

```
[MAIN-------GRAPH1]
[PAR1][PAR2][MAIN2]
[PAR2---1][PAR2--2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be something with your spacing - after some editing I am getting this to output to your desired layout:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

Row {data-height=650}
-------------------------------------

### Chart1

```{r setup, include=TRUE}
library(dygraphs)
library(flexdashboard)
library(readr)
library(xts)
```

```{r}
#graph 
```

Row {data-height=350}
-------------------------------------

### Chart1Par1

```{r}
#first parameter
```   

### Chart1Par2

```{r}
#second parameter
```

Row {data-height=650}
-------------------------------------

### Chart2

```{r}
#second chart main
```

Row {data-height=350}
-------------------------------------

### Chart2Par1

```{r}

```   

### Chart2Par2

```{r}

```
````

Comment: Affirmative, an empty line is needed before the next Row begins. Do you know how to add a column? Or will I need to just keep adding graphs to the row?

Comment: I believe since you've specified your orientation to be rows, you'll have to continue adding in that fashion. I typically use two hashes _##_ to designate a new row and a triple hast _###_ to build columns within that row.